# Backup file size inflates while in HA group

Tags: sql-server, compression, database-backups, high-availability

Does anyone know what would be the cause of inflating database backup sizes after adding a database to a high availability group? I've noticed this behavior with not only the example below but any database I've added to the HA group. I don't think I can support the HA option in my environment if this is the intended behavior.

Database File Size 322560.00 MB; 
Space Available 23444.92 MB

Full backup size with compression before HA group: 4188.3 MB

Full backup size with compression after adding to HA group: 48697.4 MB

Full backup size with compression after removing from HA group: 4925.1 MB

Full backup size with compression after re-adding to HA group: 48732.2 MB

HA group is in a healthy state with these settings: Asynchronous, Manual Failover, Allow all Connections in Primary Role, Readable in Secondary, Standard port 5022 for endpoint, Primary only for backup preferences.
Only syncing to one server at a DR state in another state.

Backup routine consists of FULL every weekend, DIFF every week night, LOG every hour and databases not in the HA group still have our standard compression ratio with that same MA plan.

Command in our custom log is:   BACKUP DATABASE [DATABASE] TO DISK = N'H:\DB\MSSQL11.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\Backup_Remote\DATABASE.bak' WITH CHECKSUM, COMPRESSION

Comment: I have no idea why - everything else being equal, of course - being part of an AG would inflate backup sizes at all, never mind 10x. Are you sure those backups are using `WITH INIT`? Can you show the actual commands you're using to generate the backups? Also what does your log look like? While part of the Availability Group, are you taking regular log backups, or just letting the log grow? (Log has to be part of the backup.) Also, is the AG healthy, meaning it is synchronizing / synchronized?

Comment: Edited original post with HA group settings and backup commands. I'm not using WITH INIT, only WITH CHECKSUM, COMPRESSION. I know CHECKSUM is on with COMPRESSION by default. I was just trying to force it.

Comment: So since you are not using `WITH INIT`, is it possible that in some cases you are looking at a .bak file that actually contains more than one backup?

Comment: I don't believe so the process of adding and removing from the HA group was all done within 10 minutes of each other and running the backup script manually for testing purposes. I'll try WITH INIT and see what size it gives me.

Comment: BACKUP DATABASE [GLASS3_CS] TO DISK = N'H:\DB\MSSQL11.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\Backup_Remote\DATABASE_INIT.bak' WITH CHECKSUM, COMPRESSION, INIT   This script just gave me a file size of 54,860.6 MB. The size went up even more.

Comment: And what is the state of the log file when you perform these backups? What are the file sizes showing in RESTORE FILELISTONLY after the backup? I suspect you are backing up a bunch of log, not a different amount of data.

Comment: Very interesting. The FILELIST for both the large backup and the much smaller one have almost the exact same size, max size, and backupsize. When I use DBCC SQLPERF (LOGSPACE) I have a log size @ 224960MB with 0.1482% used after the backup! I guess I'm not familiar enough with the backup process for a situation like this. I shrank the log file using the wizard back down to the 5GB it should be and the backup was back down to it's original size while still in the HA group.

Comment: Thank you Aaron for walking me through this. I'm new to the site and not sure how to give you props for helping me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The log is part of the backup. I suspect that you are pulling in a large log when performing the backup while the database is part of an AG. You can confirm this by comparing the file sizes when each backup takes place, or after the fact by performing a `RESTORE FILELISTONLY` for each backup. I suspect you'll see very different sizes for the log files.

Comment: Aaron you were right with this. These databases were in FULL recovery mode before adding them to the HA group and I assumed the BACKUP process was the same between my standard MA plan for a FULL RECOVERY mode database and the HA DATABASE were the same. Doing this test has shown me a problem in the management of my BACKUP and LOG file handling for maintenance. Thank you.